# Trying to create an Add extension method for an IDbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods

I'm trying to create an Extension method for my DBContext (`db`) and one of the IDbSets. I would like to be able to call the extension like this:

```
db.UploadedFile.AddFile
(
    SessionUser.ProfileId,
    model.UploadingFile.FileName,
    serverPath,
    model.ProjectSubmissionId
);
```

This seems to work, but I would like to later, after a db.SaveChanges(), get the Primary Key ID of the added value.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static class UploadedFileExtensions
{
    public static bool AddFile
    (
        this IDbSet<UploadedFile> files, 
        Guid uploadedByProfileId,
        string fileName,
        string filePath,
        Guid? associatedWithId
    )
    {
        var newFile = new UploadedFile
        {
            UploadedByProfileId = uploadedByProfileId,
            FileName = fileName,
            FilePath = filePath,
            FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName),
            Submitted = DateTime.Now,
            Modified = DateTime.Now,
            IsActive = true
        };

        if (associatedWithId != null) newFile.AssociatedWithId = associatedWithId;

        return files.AddFile(newFile);
        //return true;
    }

    public static bool AddFile(this IDbSet<UploadedFile> files, UploadedFile file)
    {
        files.Add(file);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your database context?  Are you using the repository and unit of work patterns?

Comment: When we started this project we were told we didn't need the repository pattern. I didn't agree, but that's the path we're on. I still thing we can begin using the repository pattern. What are some good sites with current examples?

Comment: You could try here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1036630/Using-Effort-Entity-Framework-Unit-Testing-Tool or here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you implement repository/unit of work, you won't need the extension method, it can be made part of your repository (preferably in a generic form). There are downsides to using the patterns as well though they can be constraining for certain things, so you shouldn't just rush into making that change

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your how your db context code is setup, you may be able to do something like this:

```
    private int GetMaxPrimaryKeyID()
    {
        return MyRepository.Items.Select(o => o.ID).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
    }
```

Where Items is:

```
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an identity ID, I don't think you can get it before it is committed to the database.

I would wrap or inherit from the context (unit of work pattern is good for this) and override the SaveChanges method with your own.
As soon as the data is committed you can see what ID value has been assigned.

Something like:

```
public override void SaveChanges()
{
    UploadedFile[] newFiles = base.ChangeTracker.Entries<UploadedFile>()
                    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
                    .Select(x => x.Entity)
                    .ToArray()

    base.SaveChanges();

    //id values should be available to you here in the newFiles array
}
```

EDIT:
On reflection, there isn't actually any need for you to override anything here. You could just use something like the above code example with your context object directly. All you really need to do is use the ChangeTracker property to inspect your entities after the commit (but before you dispose the context).